# Print xml with xsd

Tags: xml, vb.net

The below soapresponsexmldocument will print only xml but not xsd

```
Dim soapResponseXmlDocument = New XmlDocument()
soapResponseXmlDocument.LoadXml(streamReader.ReadToEnd())
TextBox1.Text = Server.HtmlDecode(soapResponseXmlDocument.InnerXml)
```

How can I print with xsd

Comment: Update your question to include the programming language and library tags. For now, I can just quess it's C#

Comment: It is related to VB.NET and xml

Comment: What do you mean by *"print xsd"*? Your `soapResponseXmlDocument` contains what you read from your `streamReader`. You need to add more details.

Comment: While loading it loads with xsd schema. But I would like to know how to print the xsd along with xml data from the xmldocument object